# Pass List<int> from Model to jQuery int[]

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I would like to pass a list of integers from my Model to jQuery. But, I am unsure of the jQuery syntax. Any help on how to fill the window.checkedCoursesArray values would be appreciated.

Model:

```
public List<int> PrintCourses { get; set; }
```

Controller:

```
var listCourseIDs = (from c in listFilteredTREs
                             select c.CourseID).ToList();
homeViewModel.PrintCourses = listCourseIDs;
```

JQuery:

```
window.checkedCoursesArray = new Array();
```

Thanks for all the help. Here is the finished jQuery/Razor code:

```
@foreach(var item in Model.PrintCourses)
{
    @:window.checkedCoursesArray.push(@item);
}
```

Comment: Don't you want to pass it in JSON format?

Comment: There is no magic, you need to make a Ajax call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

//controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult PrintCourses()
{
    var listCourseIDs = new List<int>() { 1,2,3,4,5};

    return Json(listCourseIDs, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

//view:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

            var url = '@Url.Action("PrintCourses")';
            $.get(url, function(data) {
                for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    alert(i);
                }
            });
        });

    </script>
```

====================================================================

//Controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new PrintCourses();
    model.ids = new List<int>() {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

    return View(model);
}
```

//View

```
@model MvcApplication6.Models.PrintCourses
@foreach (var id in Model.ids)
{
    @id<br/>
}
```

Comment: If you already have this list in your model, just iterate over it with a @foreach

Comment: I already have the list in the model. Can you direct me to the @foreach syntax to populate window.checkedCoursesArray?

Comment: Never mind, got it. Thanks for your help.      @foreach(var item in Model.PrintCourses)
    {
        @:window.checkedCoursesArray.push(@item);
    }